# my output CSV file is not copying the data

Tags: python, python-2.7, excel-2010, notepad++, python-3.4

I am comparing 2 CSV files, one is already there other one is prodcued by running this piece of code. Basically, it is supposed to go through the newest sheet and see if there is new row added (column A only) and make a diff file and copy the newly added row from newest file to the diff file. her eis the code i am using:

```
import os, csv, time, glob

timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

f=open("B:/Test_folder/parse_file1_"+timestr+'.csv', 'w+', newline='' )
w=csv.writer(f)
for dirs in os.listdir("B:/folder1"):
        w.writerow([dirs])

newest = max(glob.iglob('B:/Test_folder/parse_file1_*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)
oldest = min(glob.iglob('B:/Test_folder/parse_file1_*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)
with open(oldest, 'r') as t1, open(newest, 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()
with open('B:/Test_folder/file1_diff.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
outFile.close()
```

oldest file (already exist) = parse_file1_20170328_currentime

```
A
B
C
```

and 
newest file = parse_file2_20170329_currentime

```
A
B
C
D
```

expected output should be:
file1_diff

```
D
```

my problem is, even though it is creating a diff file, it is not copying D to the CSV file.
I am screwing something with the logic here, please help

Thanks

Comment: Please add trace to make sure of what are the values of `oldest` and `newest`, and if their names looks Ok, what are the values of `fileone` and `filetwo`, and share that here if the problem is still not evident.

Comment: Why are you not using `with` on first file open? Since file is not closed, I suspect that data is not flushed correctly.

Comment: Also, `outFile.close()` is pointless, as `outFile` is already closed when exiting the last `with` block.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, while your suggestions are appreciated , the problem was with execution cycle of the code. it was not able to write to a diff file coz the thread was still holding up the newest file for writting purposes. I divieded the programme in 2 parts . one for creating new files (while iterating through the directory ) and another code will compare new file with old file ( this peice of code will be called after the above code is done successfully ). This solved the problem. I know this is not the cleanest of code I could write but I am still a newbie to python and learning,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe removing whitespace will help:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line.strip() not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line.strip())